# JMeter - Listen to a port on a given IP

Tags: websocket, jmeter, bind, jmeter-5.0

I want to run a jmeter test, which listens to a port on a given ip, and prints the messages which are being sent to that port. I have tried using this:

```
SocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("<client ipAddress>"),<port number>);
def server = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(inetSocketAddress);
while(true) {
    server.accept { socket ->
        log.info('Someone is connected')
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            def line = input.newReader().readLine()
            log.info('Received message: ' + line)
        }
        log.info("Connection processed")
    }
}
```

But this is giving me error - "Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
"

Is there any alternate way to approach this? Or what changes do i need to do for the current approach to work?

Comment: I am a beginner in Jmeter and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You copied and pasted this code from the right place and it should work just fine. Evidence:

[image]

as per the [BindException documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html)

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.

So I can think of 2 options:

1. Your `<client ipAddress>` is not correct and cannot be resolved.
2. Something is already running on the `<port number>`, you cannot have 2 applications listening to the same port, the first one will be successful and another one will fail

More information:

- [Fixing java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind in Tomcat, Jetty](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/fixing-javanetbindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-JVMbind.html#ixzz6PRymyuAw)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I am getting "Address already in use: JVM_Bind". So, this is how the flow goes:
Application is running on port 1234, and another application uses "push" webservice to send data to this port 1234. Now I want my Jmeter to listen to this port 1234, and print the messages that are being recieved on this port.